# BIP 65 - how standard is it?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip, checklocktimeverify

I read in [this great thread](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18851/what-bips-are-supported-by-the-standard-client-bitcoin-core/34213) that which BIP are standards is not always obvious.
**What about BIP 65? To which extent is it standard?**

Currently, all I know is that "Miners following the developers of the "Core" Bitcoin client have been adopting BIP-65, with approximately 25% of the last found blocks claiming to be ready for the soft fork on the version string in the block header. " ... not very precise.

Thanks

Comment: I updated the thread you linked to, since it only contained information up to 0.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The softfork defined by BIP 65 activated in december 2015. This means that the whole network enforces the new rules proposed by BIP 65, and it is safe to use CLTV opcodes in scripts since then.

Comment: hey @Pieter, BIP65 also includes a section called "Replace nLockTime entirely", has this been enforced as well? is nLockTime now deprecated?

Comment: That section is under motivation, and explains one of the things that become possible to do (with more changes) due to the BIP65 rules. It does not describe BIP65 itself.